# Adding Parameters to Twitter API Using PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, twitter, twitter-oauth

I created my Twitter App using PHP, but I don't know how to add parameters in Twitter API, my code:

```
$twitter_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json'; // do not change it!

$data = array('oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
          'oauth_nonce' => time(),
          'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
          'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
          'oauth_token' => '492687736-xxxxxxxx',
          'oauth_version' => '1.0');

$baseString = buildBaseString($twitter_url, $data);

$compositeKey = $consumer_secret."&xxxxxxxx";

oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString, $compositeKey, true));

$data['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

$response = sendRequest($data, $twitter_url);

$json = json_decode($response, true);

print_r($json);
```

My code is working good with "statuses/user_timeline" (without parameters) and I got my timeline, but when using "users/show" (without parameters) I got this message:

```
 Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => 50 [message] => User not found. ) ) )
```

And when when using parameters like this:

```
$twitter_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=jack';
```

I got this message:

```
 Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => 32 [message] => Could not authenticate you. ) ) )
```

Now I want to know how to add parameters in my code?

I don't want any Twitter PHP library.